# How to remove [edit] and alike labels from Wikipedia using regex?

Tags: regex, wikipedia

I used [Regex Replace](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/regex-replace/eggkcpojddgjkakokkdhocbjebhgkonb) to remove the number labels (eg.: [1], [12], etc.) on the Wikipedia pages, and all went fine.
But when I tried removing the [edit], [hide], [show] labels, although I used \[edit\], using the global flag, for matching [edit], and then replacing it with nothing, it wouldn't yield any results within the Wikipedia site.

IIRC this used to work in the past with the extension, but there must've been taking place some changes to the site ever since.

Can regex still work with this? And if so, how can I make it work?

P.S: I've done the tests on [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/History_of_film) page.

Thank you!

Comment: There look to be spaces between the "edit" and the surrounding square brackets

Comment: You're right, it seems to be spaces. Although I tried [this](https://regex101.com/r/pukA1M/1) per your suggestion, it still wouldn't work on Wikipedia.

Comment: If this is for your own browsing experience, I'd recommend using a userscript instead - they're a whole lot more flexible

Comment: Thanks for helping out, I will take this into account.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Since 2013](https://gerrit.wikimedia.org/r/#/c/mediawiki/core/+/64365/5/includes/Skin.php), each `[ edit ]` link consists of three textNodes. However, [regex-replace](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/regex-replace/eggkcpojddgjkakokkdhocbjebhgkonb) applies regexes to [each text node separately](https://github.com/jkingsman/regex-replace/blob/5f91e14576804d40e75d83423df280ef80575df5/src/js/content_script.js#L53). This means the regex `\[edit\]` will not match such links anymore.

If you have an account, it is possible to add the following code to [your personal CSS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Special:MyPage/common.css) to hide all the links:

```
.mw-editsection {
    display: none;
}
```

Alternatively, to hide only the brackets, you can use [this](https://phabricator.wikimedia.org/T50256#495040):

```
.mw-editsection-bracket {
    display: none;
}
```

Comment: Hey, thanks for the information over how the extension works and also for the solution! Sorry for the really-really late reply, it's just I was logged out for a couple of months